# insert multiple images into svg path

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I want to insert multiple images including background color.

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1280" height="15">
        <image xlink:href="images/l1gloss.png" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="15" />
    </pattern>
</defs>

<path id="curve" style="fill:#990000 url(#img1)" d="M1279.919,13c0,0-612.618,21.562- 816.925,22.298C347.224,35.715,0,26,0,26V13c0,0,347.981,9.71,464.005,9.287C668.059,21.542,1279.919,0,1279.919,0V13z" filter="url(#f1)" stroke="none"> </path>
```

but its showing a black curve. but if i remove either fill color or #img1 from the style it works.
Now i want to use both fill color and #img in the curve path.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't  fill the path with color and pattern together. You can do this task by creating two paths. Path with background color should come behind of the other one.

```
<path class="curve" style="fill:#990000" d="M1279.919,13c0,0-612.618,21.562- 816.925,22.298C347.224,35.715,0,26,0,26V13c0,0,347.981,9.71,464.005,9.287C668.059,21.542,1279.919,0,1279.919,0V13z" filter="url(#f1)" stroke="none"> </path> 
<path class="curve" style="url(#img1)" d="M1279.919,13c0,0-612.618,21.562- 816.925,22.298C347.224,35.715,0,26,0,26V13c0,0,347.981,9.71,464.005,9.287C668.059,21.542,1279.919,0,1279.919,0V13z" filter="url(#f1)" stroke="none"> </path>
```

Comment: hi, Thankyou very much.. Can I use mask/clip-mask for this i.e      <div id="maskDiv"> <svg id="svgMask"></svg> </div>, If this is the format so here can i mask #maskDiv with #svgMask element. Is this possible.

Answer (score 0):

Combine the background color into the pattern using a rect, as below. (BTW you have an unreferenced filter (f1) in your sample code above - and you haven't specified the aspect ratio behavior for your image - corrected below)

```
<svg width="100%" height="100%" viewBox=
0 0 2000 2000"">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="1280" height="15">
      <rect fill="#ff0000" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="15"/>  
      <image xlink:href="http://asia.olympus-imaging.com/products/dslr/e520/sample/images/sample_03.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="15" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"/>

    </pattern>
</defs>

<path id="curve"  d="M1279.919,13 c0,0 -612.618,21.562 -816.925,22.298C347.224,35.715,0,26,0,26V13c0,0,347.981,9.71,464.005,9.287C668.059,21.542,1279.919,0,1279.919,0V13z" fill="url(#img1)" stroke="none"> </path>

</svg>
```